# Execute web page js from chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this js function in my web page html code.

```
function update() {
    document.getElementById( "textbox ").value = updatetext;
}
```

When I execute "update()" from chrome console, it works.
But if I execute from chrome extension,

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "update();"}, function(result){});
```

It says update is not defined. But if I replace with "alert('ok')", It works.
Then I execute

```
eval("update()")
```

in Chrome extension content script. It also says "update is not defined."

So what can i do to call js function on web page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Comment: Or even better with regards to your questions in comments: [Executing code at page-level from Background.js and returning the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140443/executing-code-at-page-level-from-background-js-and-returning-the-value/26141393)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome executes content scripts in a sandbox, so you need to inject an inline script to interact with the webpage:

```js
var injectedCode = 'update()';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ injectedCode +')();'));
(document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```

Comment: thanks, if i want to execute a js function with return value? how can i get the return value? @KAdot

Comment: You can store return value as a member of hidden DOM element, then read it from content script.

Comment: Can you post a code example? i tried document.documentElement.setAttribute(), but it can only set String value, does not work on js object. Is there some way to return a js object? @KAdot

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify to return object.

Comment: But if I want to pass an DOM element, how to achieve this?@KAdot

Comment: It's impossibe because of sandbox.