# Why is chrome.runtime undefined when running JS inside a page from a content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension (my first one) and I want to send messages from the extension to the current tab.

I am following the documentation:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage

The extension loads a small external JS into the tab's HTML, which contains the following code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request)
    }
);
```

As soon as the JS is loaded I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMessage' of undefined`.

Opening console and typing `chrome`, I can see that the runtime is not a property of `chrome`.

It looks like I am doing something wrong, but what? Do I need to add something to the `manifest.json` file?

Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're inserting JavaScript into a page with a `<script>` tag, it executes in the page's context.

Sometimes [it is desirable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script): that's the only way to access page-level JavaScript objects.

But in your case it means that the code does not have access to Chrome APIs, as it is "the same" as the page's code.

You need to look into communicating between [page-level and content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739774/chrome-extension-passing-object-from-page-to-context-script/26740141#26740141), or between [page-level and background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140443/executing-code-at-page-level-from-background-js-and-returning-the-value/26141393#26141393) (spoiler, in most cases needs a context script proxy anyway).

Comment: I'm extremely stumped on this.  I have a chrome extension with 5K users that works 99% of the time.  The other 1% of the time there are errors saying that chrome.runtime is undefined.  I can't figure out how chrome.runtime could possibly be undefined sometimes.  I'd love any guidance you could provide on this.  mike at scribbl.co (would really appreciate some help here)

Comment: @MikeSallese I am experiencing the same, rare random errors logged in Sentry. I cannot replicate, neither can users. Have you ever reached any consensus on what may be going on?

Comment: My guess: it might have to do with orphaned content scripts when their parent extension is updated and thus reloaded. That causes the API to break in many unpredictable ways. Back when I was investigating that, my observations can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131526/934239 - it's possible that this "undefined behavior" changed since. But also maybe it's not that.

Answer (score 10):

or it could just be a Heisenbug which only appears under certain circumstances. in my case, closing the chrome://extensions tab and refreshing my target caused chrome.runtime to be available again. [Why is chrome.runtime undefined in the content script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234623/why-is-chrome-runtime-undefined-in-the-content-script)