I can't use Kuroshiro library in my chrome extension
I'm learning Javascript and I thought I can make a small project but I'm having so many errors I have no idea what is wrong with my code. I'm trying to make a chrome extension that adds furigana to a japanese text, for this I'm using Kuroshiro library.
I believe I installed it correctly and it works when I run it locally. But when I upload it as an extension it doesn't seem to work. Here is my manifest.json,
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    
  "web_accessible_resources": [

    {
      "resources": [
        "lib/kuroshiro.min.js","lib/kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji.min.js","add_furigana.js","content3.js","dict/*"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "content3.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

And here is my content3.js,
// Function to inject Kuroshiro and its dependencies into the web page
function injectKuroshiro() {
    // Create script elements for Kuroshiro and its dependencies
    const kuroshiroScript = document.createElement('script');
    kuroshiroScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('lib/kuroshiro.min.js');
    kuroshiroScript.onload = function() {
        const analyzerScript = document.createElement('script');
        analyzerScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('lib/kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji.min.js');
        analyzerScript.onload = function() {
            const add_furiganaScript = document.createElement('script');
            add_furiganaScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('add_furigana.js');
            document.head.appendChild(add_furiganaScript);

        };
        document.head.appendChild(analyzerScript);
    };
    document.head.appendChild(kuroshiroScript);
}

injectKuroshiro();

and add_furigana.js,
async function initializeKuroshiro() {
  const kuroshiro = new Kuroshiro();
  try {
    // Initialize Kuroshiro with the Kuromoji analyzer
    const dictPath = chrome.runtime.getURL('dict/'); // Assuming 'dict' is your folder name
    await kuroshiro.init(new KuromojiAnalyzer({ dicPath: dictPath }));
    
    // Convert the given text to hiragana
    const result = await kuroshiro.convert("感じ取れたら手を繋ごう、重なるのは人生のライン and レミリア最高！", { to: "hiragana" });
    
    // Output the converted text
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Kuroshiro initialization failed:", err);
  }
}
initializeKuroshiro();

It gives me this error,
And if I remove dictPath I get this error
I'm sure I have the right dict files, but I have no idea what causes this, and chatgpt doesn't help at all.
And the weird thing is it works in popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="lib/kuroshiro.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji.min.js"></script>
    <script src="add_furigana.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>

Sorry if this is a stupid question but what am I missing here?

Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207129/why-is-chrome-runtime-undefined-when-running-js-inside-a-page-from-a-content-scr

So if I understand correctly, content scripts can't access to other scripts so my content3.js can't see library files, and the scripts loaded into the page (page context) doesn't have access to the chrome API, that's why I'm getting an error with getURL. To solve this I need DOM events, is this correct? But then why does popup.html work?

The getURL called by content3.js is successful. The getURL called by add_furigana.js fails. Therefore, I think it would be best to incorporate the add_furigana.js processing into content3.js.

If I do that I get "Kuroshiro is not defined" error. And if I print the dict path using console.log(chrome.runtime.getURL('dict/')) in content3.js and manually copy it to add_furigana.js I still get missing files error.

Delete content3.js and load kuroshiro.min.js, kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji.min.js, and add_furigana.js as content scripts.
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "dict/*"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "lib/kuroshiro.min.js",
        "lib/kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji.min.js",
        "add_furigana.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]


I could've sworn that I tried this and it didn't work but I tried it now and it works, thank you.
