# Show on Chrome Extension Popup a late window variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am still learning about all the Chrome Extension scheme, with background/content/popup scripts.

I have a page that runs some script on $(document).ready() and it sets a new variable in the window, that i can access in the website like "window.newVariableHere".
I want to be able to echo the content of this variable whenever i open the Extension popup.

I tried, in the popup.js (which is being called in my popup.html) do a:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
```

But it wont show the new variable (that i am sure it was created).
Any ideas on a better way to do this?

Thanks for all the ideas

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` gives you the `window` object *of the background page*, not the actual displayed website in the current tab.

Please read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). (All Chrome extension developers must read and understand that)

You will need a content script, and worse than that, you will [need a page-level script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26141393/934239) since `window` object of the page is isolated from content scripts.

Comment: That's basically exactly what i was looking for, i was just kinda lost on where/what to look after in the documentation. Thank you very much.