# Call content script function from new dom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is a very trivial example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "/js/external/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", 
        "/js/content_script.js"
      ],
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
function demo() {
  alert('demo');
}

$(function() {
  $( "body" ).prepend( 
    "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Press me\" onclick=\"demo()\" />"
  );
});
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: demo is not defined
```

How do I get the functionality to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is [Isolated Worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

Content scripts have their own JS context. You define `demo` in the content script context.

However, when adding a DOM node like that, the `onclick` attribute will refer to the page context, which does not have the `demo` function.

You have many options here.

1. The simplest is to attach a listener to the node in the content script context:

   ```
   var node = $('<input type="button" value="Press me"/>').click(demo);
   $("body").prepend(node);
   ```
2. Another way is to define `demo()` in the page context. To do that, you need to [inject the code to the page context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) via a `<script>` tag.

   ```
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.textContent = demo.toString();
   (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
   script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
   ```

   Do note that this code won't have access to content script context and Chrome API. However, it may be useful, as it will have access to page's own JavaScript.
3. If you need a mix of two (access to both page and content script), you'll need to [make the two contexts communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26141393/934239).

Comment: i really surprised :)

Comment: Can you subscribe to events on the page, eg. scroll events?

Comment: That would be a different question. Do a bit of research first, and if it's still unclear - ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = $('<input type="button" value="Press me"/>').click(demo);
$("body").prepend(node);
```

Another way is to define `demo()` in the page context. To do that, you need to inject the code to the page context via a `<script>` tag.