# is there possible calling gwt jsni method with chrome extension using chrome.tab.executeScript?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension

I have a gwt project that wrap in chrome extensions.

In GWT, I export a java method to jsni called:

```
Java Method: sendMessage(String msg);
export jsni: $wnd.sendMessage = function(msg) { ... };
```

then in chrome extension, I execute:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "sendMessage('hello');"}
```

but not thing happened, I've tried:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "alert('hello');"}
```

and it just works fine. but it just can't call my gwt jsni method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome content scripts exist in [an isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

`$wnd.sendMessage` is exported in the page context, and not accessible from a content script.

You'll need to inject code into the page itself (with a `<script>` tag) to access it.

See [this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) on the topic, and this question can also be of use: [Executing code at page-level from Background.js and returning the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26140443/934239)

Comment: thank you @Xan, I have successful call JSNI method in background.js, but  I have another question that I don't know how to pass a json format string in it. while I pass "sendMessage(123);"  it works, but not work when I pass "sendMessage(jsonString);"

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem, when pass a json string, you have to encode the string to prevent double quotes/special character in the string, here is my code:

assume the data format is:

```
var data = '{"abc":123,"cde":"kkk"}';
```

then encode the data:

```
var param = '\'' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '\'';
```

put then data into the code to execute:

```
var codeToExec = [
        'var actualCode = "window.sendMessage(' + param + ');"',
        'var script = document.createElement("script");',
        'script.textContent = actualCode;',
        '(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);',
        'script.remove();'
    ].join('\n');

chrome.tabs.executeScript(mainTabId, {code: codeToExec});
```