# Data storage inaccessible to Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way of storing data (for example, a CSRF token) that cannot be accessed by a Chrome extension under any circumstances?

Ideally I would like to store information that would remain secure even if a naïve user granted all permissions to an extension.

Comment: In general, if you want to store data securely, don't store it in the browser.

Comment: What's the point? The user can get at it by using the Javascript console, and then copy it into the extension.

Comment: Presumably, you want something accessible to a page's JavaScript?

Comment: @Xan - yes. I was wondering if there was somewhere that was accessible to the page but inaccessible to an extension.

Comment: @Barmar - of course, the user has full control. I'm trying to prevent a rogue extension from accessing privileged data (like a CSRF token) without the user's knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was somewhere that was accessible to the page but inaccessible to an extension.

Consider the so-called page-level scripts. A content script can [inject a `<script>` tag into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script), and it will be executed in the same environment as the page.

It can then extract your hypothetical secure data and [communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140443/executing-code-at-page-level-from-background-js-and-returning-the-value/26141393#26141393) with the rest of the extension.

What's worse, you can't reasonably prevent this injection, as it [ignores your page's CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions).