# Using third party JQuery library in Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

How to use third party jQuery plugin in Chrome extension? I want to use jquery-confirm or alertify in background.js or content.js file? How can I do that?

Comment: Try to refer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792273/using-third-party-libraries). You will also be interested to follow the answers in the github post ["How add jQuery or third parties library?"](https://github.com/HaNdTriX/generator-chrome-extension-kickstart/issues/15).

Comment: Thanks for your help